# Update all fields of nested document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to increase all fields of `totalUnreadMessages`.

Example data:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5e7f4b739d22a0ffd57afc5f"),
  "totalUnreadMessages": {
    "5e5008406ddd5061bf8c47fe": 0,
    "5e7f4b739d22a0ffd57afc5f": 0
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do that in one query? Or can I get fields of totalUnreadMessages, iterate through them and execute the query? Or, maybe, I can match fields for a (regex) pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's possible to achieve this through raw query but you can mix some javascript and do the following:

```
db.collection.find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
    for(prop in doc["totalUnreadMessages"]) {
        ++doc["totalUnreadMessages"][prop]
    }
    db.collection.save(doc)
})
```

Comment: Won't this query the database document.totalUnreadMessages.length times? There are always at least 2 fields in `totalUnreadMessages`, so it will query the database 3 times.
I can query once, get keys of totalUnreadMessages and update then, but, if it's possible to do it with one query, it will be much better.

Comment: not exactly, it will query only one time and cycle through all your properties in totalUnreadMessages, increment it and update complete document.

Comment: Ah, yes. It seemed to that save() is  inside the for loop ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Edit: fix shrug emoticon

Comment: this will make 1 query to find all the matching documents and 1 query to update every document, so if you have 100 documents that match the query you will have 100 queries to update those documents and 1 to find them.